# Read element inside element from XML in SAX or Dom

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax

```
<rootNode>
    <Movies>
    <Movie id=1>
         <title> title1</title>
         <Actors>
            <Actor>Actor1</Actor>
            <Actor>Actor2</Actor>
         <Actors>
    </Movie>
    </Movies>
    <performers >
        <performer id=100>
             <name>name1</name>
             <movie idref=1/>
        </performer>
    </performers>
</rootNode>
```

Question1: I only want to get the movie under the movies. I tried both of DOM and SAX. It also returns the  under performers. How can I avoid this by using SAX or DOM

```
DOM:
doc.getElementsByTagName("movie");
SAX:
public void startElement(String uri, String localName,String qName, 
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {

        if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("movie"))
```

Question2: How can I get the element inside element (Actor under movies) by using DOM or SAX?

Basically,  what I want to do is output the data in order.

```
1,title, Actor1,Actor2
100,name1,1
```

Comment: It doesn't look like a valid XML to me.

Comment: My original XML file is very large, so I made up the similar XMl. I edited it.

Comment: Java supports XPath for this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Comment: Note your xml is still not valid

Answer (score 2):

```
doc.getElementsByTagName("movies")[0].childNodes;
```

gets you all the `movies/movie` nodes (watch for lower-/upper-case!). See here http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_intro.asp for a short tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

[XPath](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html) is designed for this type of extraction.  For your example file, the query would be something like the following.  For simplicity, I assumed your xml was in a `res/raw`, but in practice you will need to create the `InputSource` from where ever you are getting your xml.

```
    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    String expression = "/rootNode/Movies/Movie";
    try {
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(expression, doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```